# Text field responder incompatibility iOS4 -> iOS 5

Tags: uitextfield, first-responder, ios5

Curious problem:

Two UITextFields, managed by a single controller, enabled for keyboard input.  If one enters a value in field #1 and presses "Next" on the KB, the blinking cursor jumps to field #2 just fine and everything's OK.  But (only in iOS 5) if one ***touches*** field #2 instead of pressing "Next", the cursor jumps to field #2 but doesn't blink and the KB is dead.

Stepping through the code, I find that in the first case the sequence is:

- textFieldShouldReturn:field#1 (which does a resign first responder for #1)
- textFieldDidEndEditing:field#1 (which does a resign for #1 and a become for #2)
- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:field#2

In the second case (when the field is touched vs using "Next") the sequence is:

- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:field#2
- textFieldDidEndEditing:field#1
- textFieldShouldBeginEditing:field#2 (again)
- textFieldDidEndEditing:field#2 (which does a resign for BOTH #1 and #2)

Obviously, when the resign for #2 is done that kills the KB, but *WHY* is iOS 5 making the call to DidEndEditing with field #2???  And how could one circumvent this?

### Update

Added a hook for textFieldShouldEndEditing.  It's called before textFieldDidEndEditing for field#1, but not before textFieldDidEndEditing for field#1.  Though, curiously, textFieldShouldBeginEditing *is* called just before textFieldDidEndEditing for field#2.  Smells like an out-and-out "dupe error" in the iOS code.

### Update 2

iOS 5 does not handle resign/become calls out of testFieldDidEndEditing.  See below for circumvention.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the conclusion that iOS 5 does not (correctly) handle the case of having `resignFirstResponder`/`becomeFirstResponder` calls inside `textFieldDidEndEditing`.  Moved the logic (more or less) to `textFieldShouldReturn` (touch kind of takes care of itself), and now it seems to work OK.